# Add two table and need the result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is table 1:

```
address_id   company_id
12           59
316          59
321          59
322          59
323          59
```

This is table 2:

```
address_id   company_id
316          59
321          59
322          59
323          59
325          59
```

Need output:

Output table

```
address_id   company_id
12           59
316          59
321          59
322          59
323          59
325          59
```

This is in MySQL.Please help me for this output

Answer (score 1):

You simply need [`UNION [DISTINCT]`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to merge the two (similar) tables into a single table; while removing the duplicate rows from the result:

```
(SELECT address_id, company_id FROM table1)
  UNION /* DISTINCT behaviour is default */
(SELECT address_id, company_id FROM table2)
ORDER BY address_id  /* Sorts the unionized result by address_id */
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this query

```
INSERT IGNORE
  INTO table_1 
SELECT *
  FROM table_2
     ;
```

It will merge both table.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp
check this out

SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT address_id, company_id FROM table_1 
UNION 
SELECT address_id, company_id FROM table_2;
```

UNION will work like DISTINCT in this case.Try it